# MVC multiple DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a table view from a list of items and I have in each row a DropDownListFor to select values from another list. I want to map each Name with a corresponding Code. If some Names are allready mapped how can I display some DropdownLists with the selected value?
Thank you.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach(var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Code, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectCodes)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Is this in a form that your submitting (you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls)?

Comment: I think I can submit if I use for(int i=0; ...) loop

Comment: Yes, you need a `for` loop - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Code, ...` if you want to submit a form. When using `DropDownListFor()` inside a loop, you need to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration (its an unfortunate limitation of the helper), but another option is an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: I have no problem to generate many times the same SelectList. I want in each row to have a different item selected or no item for the unmapped.

Comment: Since `ViewBag.SelectCodes` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, then you need `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Code, new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectCodes, "Value", "Text", Model[i].Code))`. I'll add an answer a bit later showing the preferred method using an `EditorTemplate` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if this view is part of a form your submitting to a controller method, then you need to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` for your model. Your `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model and its also generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop and its necessary to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration and set the `Selected` property. Using a `for` loop your view needs to be (the model must be `IList<T>`)

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Code, new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectCodes, "Value", "Text", Model[i].Code))
}
```

Note this is based on `ViewBag.SelectCodes` already being a `SelectList`, which is not really necessary. It could be something like `new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectCodes, "ID", "Name", Model[i].Code)` where `SelectCodes` is a collection of objects containing properties `ID` and `Name`.

A better alternative is to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model. Assuming your model is `MyModel.cs`, then create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyModel.cshtml` (the name of the template must match the name of the class)

```
@model MyModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code, (SelectList)ViewData["SelectCodes"])</td>
</tr>
```

Then in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
....
<table>
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { SelectCodes = ViewBag.SelectCodes })
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `EditorFor()` method is passing the `SelectList` to the template using `AdditionalViewData` and the method will correctly generate the html for each item in the collection without have to generate new `SelectList`'s.