# MVC Display object value in dropdownlist in edit view of object collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I have some problem in communicating data from controller to view and vise-versa. Here is my controller:

```
ViewBag.MANAGER_IDS = new SelectList(db.APP_USERS, "USER_ID", "USER_ID");
return View(app_users_manager);
```

What I want to do is to populate populate manager ids in a dropdownlist for each object (i.e. app_users_manager)

Following is my view:

```
@model List<HRM.Models.APP_USERS_MANAGER>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit managers";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UserManager", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table>
        <tr class="myidtr">
            <th>Manager role</th>
            <th>Manager</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr class="mytr">
                @Html.Hidden("app_users_manager[" + @i + "].USER_ID", Model[i].USER_ID)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].APP_MANAGERS.MANAGER_DESCRIPTION)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("app_users_manager[" + @i + "].USER_ID_MANAGER", ViewBag.USER_ID_MANAGER as List<SelectListItem>, "-Select manager-")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

I am able to do so using the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model[i].USER_ID_MANAGER, ViewBag.USER_ID_MANAGER as List<SelectListItem>, "-Select manager-", new { @Id = "Test"})
```

but then I do not get updated value in my controller. or if I do following then I am not be able to get value on the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("USER_ID_MANAGER", ViewBag.USER_ID_MANAGER as List<SelectListItem>, "-Select manager-")
```

Can somebody suggest whats wrong in there? Any help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].USER_ID_MANAGER, new SelectList(ViewBag.MANAGER_IDS, "Value", "Text", ), "-Select manager-")`

Comment: Refer also the 2nd part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332019/mvc-multiple-dropdownlistfor/34333037#34333037)

Comment: Thanks for response stephen, I still got the same result i.e. object property value still not set in dropdownlist

Comment: Did you read the answer I linked to? And have you set the value of `USER_ID_MANAGER` in each object in your collection before you pass the collection to the view? If so, then it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].USER_ID_MANAGER, new SelectList(ViewBag.MANAGER_IDS, "Value", "Text", Model[i].USER_ID_MANAGER), "-Select manager-")`

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I am now able to set values in dropdownlist however post method in controller still receive this value as null. this is how my post method looks like 'public ActionResult Edit(List<APP_USERS_MANAGER> app_users_manager)' this is because I bind my collection in view with app_users_manager

Comment: The `USER_ID_MANAGER` property will bind correctly but the `USER_ID` property wont. It needs to be `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].USER_ID)` and change the POST method parameter to `Edit(List<APP_USERS_MANAGER> model)`

Comment: looks like more elegent method than I'd used. Will try this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable comments Stephen. I was able to view and persist changed values. For future references to similar problem to anyone, here is how I fixed it:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string user_id)
{
ViewBag.USER_ID_MANAGER = new SelectList(db.APP_USERS, "USER_ID", "USER_ID");
            return View(app_users_manager);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(List<APP_USERS_MANAGER> app_users_manager)
{
return View(app_users_manager);
}
```

This is how my view looks:

```
@Html.DropDownList("app_users_manager[" + @i + "].USER_ID_MANAGER", new SelectList(ViewBag.USER_ID_MANAGER, "Value", "Text", Model[i].USER_ID_MANAGER), "-Select manager-")
```